# Why is my PHP script returning different results on similar inputs?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, forms

**Background:** I am doing ajax calls to a PHP script which returns data to fill a form based on some file key a user inputs. This form is used so users may edit an incorrectly inputted file key from their original submission.

**Problem:** If a user wanted to edit a file key, they input it into a text box, hit a button for an ajax pull, the form fills, they can then correct their mistakes and submit. However, if they try to edit the new file key again, the form will not fill and I am getting no results returned from the query. This is the **php** script I have been using to pull the data from the server.

A sample file key might be: **10000010000-0D-MAN**.
This is a good response: **10000010000-0D-MAN,N/A,amibaguest,dfgfdgfd,Electrical**

This is the response I get on a newly edited file key: **Nothing returned. Id: 20000010000-0D-MAN**.

Really baffled at the moment. If more information is needed, please let me know.

```
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("database", $dbhandle)
    or die("Could not select database");

$id = $_GET['param'];
if(isset($_GET['param'])) {
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT a.File_key, a.Name, a.Uploader, a.File_descriptor, b.keyword1 FROM files as a, keyword as b WHERE a.File_key='%s' AND a.File_key=b.File_key", mysql_real_escape_string($id));
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result === FALSE) {
            echo mysql_error();
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1) {
            while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $file_key = $myrow["File_key"];
                    $name = $myrow["Name"];
                    $uploader = $myrow["Uploader"];
                    $file_desc = $myrow["File_descriptor"];
                    $keyword = $myrow["keyword1"];
                    $text_out .=  $file_key.",".$name.",".$uploader.",".$file_desc.",".$keyword;
            }// end while
    } else {
            $text_out = " Nothing returned. Id: ".$id;
    }// end else    
}// endif
echo $text_out;
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"no results returned from the query"_? Is the page not hit, are you getting `mysql_num_rows($result)!=1`, or something else entirely? Is it possible that your query is returning more than one row?

Comment: Best guess- Check your update code. You have a JOIN in your select SQL. May be you are updating the file key somewhere. If yes, are you updating it in both the tables?

Comment: Anuj thank you. I was not updating the file key in the second table. That was the issue.